# Condition getting getting called where it is not supposed to be

Tags: regex, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <para><content-style font-style="bold">18/8/7</content-style> <content-style font-style="italic">(2) Here is the content</content-style>&#x2014;Contributory negligence  accident 
<content-style font-style="italic">second v/w datav. </content-style> </para>
</body>
```

and the below XSL.

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para[node()[position() = 1 and self::content-style[matches(., '(\w+)/(\w+)')]]]">
        <div class="para">
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)">
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                            <a name="{concat('P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2),'-',regex-group(3))}"/>
                            <span class="phrase">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </span>
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\w+)/(\w+)">
                                <xsl:matching-substring>
                                    <a name="{concat('P',regex-group(1),'-',regex-group(2))}"/>
                                    <span class="phrase">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </span>
                                    <xsl:text>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:matching-substring>
                                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                            </xsl:analyze-string>
                        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::content-style[1]/text())]"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content-style">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./@format">
                <span class="format-{@format}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:variable name="fontStyle">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('font-style-',@font-style)"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <span class="{$fontStyle}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </span>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:transform>
```

here the problem that i face is the regex is getting called on both `content-styles`, but i want it to be called only on the `content-style` where there is no preceding data(text or node), i.e. only on the node like `<para><content-style>` but not on like `<para>(text/node)<content-style>`.

**Current O/p:**

```
<div class="para"><a name="P18-8-7"></a><span class="phrase">18/8/7</span> (2) Here is the content—Contributory negligence  accident 
         second <a name="Pv-w"></a><span class="phrase">v/w</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; datav.   —Contributory negligence  accident 

      </div>
```

**Expected O/P**

```
  <div class="para"><a name="P18-8-7"></a><span class="phrase">18/8/7</span> (2) Here is the content—Contributory negligence  accident 
             second <span class="font-style-italic">second v/w datav.</span>
          </div>
```

please let me know where am i going wrong and how can i fix this.
[Working Demo](http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHTq)

Thanks

Comment: I don't think I understand the logic behind all this. First of all, make your Working Demo consistent with the question, it has a different input and more templates than the SO question. Then, please explain why there are two templates that match `para`, why one is a named template and why you need `analyze-string`.

Comment: Hi @MathiasMüller, Thanks for the response, here i use regex because i want to create a phrase from the the `content-style` that matches the regex, this phrase is just for linking purpose, and i have given 2 paras just to show the differentiation stating that there are two matches, where in the first selects just the `<para>` and second matches `<para><content-style>`, thanks for pointing this, i'm removing this and making working demo same as the SO Question.

Comment: Still, no consistency. You've removed the first template matching `para`, but now the part about the `@align` attribute is gone. Does it no longer matter? And what happens to `para` elements where `content-style` is not the first child? The output samples still do not have `body` or `html`, do you want them or not?

Comment: I dont need `body` or `html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your current XSLT, at the moment when you apply your regex (with analyze-string) you are positioned on a `para` element, not a `content-style`, and so doing `select="."` will get the string value of the entire `para` element, not just the first node.

What you may need to do is change it to this, so it just does analyse the first `content-string` (which you know is the first node from the condition in the template match)

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="content-style[1]" regex="(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)">
```

There is also a problem with this `apply-templates` in your current template

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::content-style[1]/text())]"/>
```

I think what you are trying to do is select the child nodes of `para` apart from the first `child-element`. If so, you should change it to this

```
 <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[position() > 1]"/>
```

This may give you what you need.

Alternatively, you could change your current template that matches `para` to one that matches the first `content-style` instead:

```
<xsl:template match="content-style[not(preceding-sibling::node())][matches(., '(\w+)/(\w+)')]">
```

As this has a condition on it, it will have a higher priority than the template that matches `content-style` on its own.

As a very simplistic example try this XSLT as a basis

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content-style[not(preceding-sibling::node())][matches(., '(\w+)/(\w+)')]">
        <content-style class="first">
            <!-- Regex here! -->
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </content-style>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="content-style">
        <content-style class="other">
            <!-- Other -->
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </content-style>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, you might need to add a `strip-space` element to your XSLT, otherwise any white space before the first `content-style` would also count as a proper node.

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
```